# How do I get the path to the current C# source code file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, path

How do I get the path to the current C# source code file, or the directory the file is stored in? (I'm answering this question myself because I didn't find anything on it with a Google search.)

(**Note:** This is not asking for `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`, which gives the path to the executable, nor `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, which gives the directory the process was invoked from.)

Comment: usually the source code *won't be on the machine running it* - that's just a privilege of being a developer... you *can* get the paths from the build machine, though...

Comment: @MarcGravell Good point. Yeah, this isn't intended for production code; it's only when you're running the code on the same machine that you compiled it on.

Answer (score 35):

Do this:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

private static string GetThisFilePath([CallerFilePath] string path = null)
{
    return path;
}

var path = GetThisFilePath(); // path = @"path\to\your\source\code\file.cs"
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // directory = @"path\to\your\source\code"
```

**How it works:** Roslyn specially recognizes the `CallerFilePath`, `CallerLineNumber`, and `CallerMemberName` attributes (the last one might look familiar to you if you've done some MVVM programming). At compile-time, it populates parameters marked with these attributes with the actual file path / line number / member name of the caller. If you compile and decompile the above code, the assignment to `path` will look like

```
var path = GetThisFilePath(@"path\to\your\source\code\file.cs");
```